# Excel Auto number row based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in excel which creates a sequential number in a column (B) depending on the contents of another column. Currently, there are two possibilities of what could be in Column A ("BI" or "GF"). So I want the data to look like this

```
    COL A    COLB
     BI       1
     BI       2
     GF       1
     BI       3
     GF       2
     GF       3
     BI       4
     BI       5
```

I've tried several attempts to do this but can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In B2, try this formula:
   =CountIf(A$2:A2,A2)

Comment: So simple yet I just couldn't see it, works a treat, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the offset equation.

The first cell in COL B will look similar to this:

**=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(A$1$1:A1,0,0),A1)**

The second should look like this:

**=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(A$1$1:A2,0,0),A2)**

Drag this down in Col B as far as desired. If you are using a table this should autofill.

**Explanation:**
Essentially you are using the OFFSET formula to create a dynamic range.
The A$1$ serves as the start of your range by making this an absolute reference and the A1 will serve as the end of your range.

By making the ending cell a relative reference, the array the COUNTIFS function search will never go beyond the row the of the cell the formula is relative of.

In your example, the formula in the first row in Col B would result in 1. The reason is the OFFSET returns the array of A$1$:A1 and the COUNTIFS searches through that array and returns a count of all cells equal to A1 which is "BI".

The second row retains the original starting cell for the array of A$1$ however the end of the array is A2. So the COUNTIFS function sees the new array to search through to be A$1$:A2. The COUNTIFS then searchs through each cell equal to A2 which like A1 is "BI". There are two cells equal to "BI" in the new array and thus the reult is 2.

How this works like you want is displayed in the third row of Col B.

The OFFSET functions simply expands the array size to A$1$:A3. The COUNTIFS will work as it normally does, it takes the array, called the criteriarange in Excel, and performs a count for all items that equal A3. A3 in this case is equal to "GF" and in the array A$1$:A3 there are two cells equal to "BF" and one equal to "GF".

Hope this helps!